# Why no current will pass through 3 and 6 ohm resistance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

Why no current will pass through 3 and 6 ohm resistance ?

Comment: Do you know how to compute parallel resistances? What is the resistance of that short circuit across the 3 and 6 resistors?

Comment: Depends whether the wires are superconducting or not

Comment: Hint:  there is no voltage across either of the resistors in parallel with the (ideal) wire.

Answer (score 2):

Current only flows if there is a voltage across the resistors.

If the resistors are ideally short circuited, no current can flow through them.

Answer (score 0):

Current would naturally not prefer to take a path with greater opposition. In such situations, the ratio of current passing through each wire is in the inverse ratio of its resistance. 
Apply kirchoff law and verify for yourself.

Comment: How come my comment is disliked looking at the other answer?